# Why is there a gap underneath my header in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css

I just started building a website http://preview.hksenet.hk in HTML5 and CSS.

But, I can't figure out why there is a big gap right under the header in IE. Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is to do with `#searchmenudiv`.

You can fix it by:

- Setting `position:relative` on `#pageheader`.
- Setting `position:absolute; top:0; right:0` on `#searchmenudiv`.

Read more here: http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

In general, that's a more robust technique for what you're trying to do than using `position:relative; top:-116px`. For example, if you ever changed the height of the header, you'd have to update your `-116px` magic number. With my suggestion, `#searchmenudiv` will always be at the top right, no matter what.

Comment: It just work! Thanks. However, when I try to apply the same trick to #logo
`#logo
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
}`
The header disappear, why?

Comment: When you apply `position: absolute`, the element is removed from normal flow. When both `#searchmenudiv` and `#logo` have `position: absolute`, the only element left in normal flow inside `#pageheader` is `#logindisplay`, which has `margin-top: -130px`, and through [collapsing margins](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing) everything is pulled up. You should leave `#logo` as it is - there's nothing wrong with how it's been positioned.